# "I can’t *make effort with* my arms, after surgery" - Is this correct?

Tags: word-choice

After surgery, we have to avoid lifting things or making any kind of effort with the part of body that is related to the surgery, in order to preserve that part of the body and avoid further health complications. Would you use "make effort with" to talk about this?

"I can’t *make effort with* my arms, after surgery".

"My doctor said I shouldn't *make effort with* my leg, afer surgery"

I don't know, I don't feel this is right... How would you say this?

Comment: My doctor says I should stay off my leg after surgery.  I shouldn’t do anything strenuous.  I should take it easy.  It all depends on what exactly you’re allowed to do.

Comment: I must rest my arms / leg.

Comment: ‘‘No heavy lifting.’’

Answer (score 1):

"Make effort with" seems awkward. Too many words. How about "exert"?

Comment: Can I say "I can't exert my arms"?

Comment: In fairness, though it is not strictly idiomatic in an everyday sense, I could imagine it being the type of thing a doctor might say in order to get the point across - "It's alright to use your arms, but do not make (too much) effort with them, just for now".

Comment: @WS2 The doctor example is fine, for two reasons: 1) it modifies _effort_ with ‘too much’ (_effort_ is rarely used absolutely, with no article or modifier); and 2) it doesn’t have the same kind of epistemic (or perhaps even deontic) modality that the original in the question has. “Don’t make too much effort with your arm” sounds quite natural, but “I can’t make effort with my arm” sounds very unidiomatic to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes I agree. I was just trying to defend an imagined NHS GP, busy and overworked. But perhaps more common, at least in the UK would be "Don't make too much of an effort with your arms just now...."